Is there a way to check if the size of structs or offsets of struct members vary between gcc and clang?
I recently ran into an issue where it appeared IPC using shared memory broke between two applications.  When compiled with the same compiler (gcc11 or clang14) they could communicate successfully, but with different compilers the communication broke down.
I strongly suspect that the sizes and/or offsets of the objects being written to shared memory are different depending on the compiler version.
Is there an easy way to verify this for a large number of structs?

Recommendation: Don't use structures as a comm protocol because you will run into this problem pretty much every time. Serialize instead so everyone can read/write.

@user4581301 Noted, but unfortunately far too late for this project

Even if you find a tool, compiler options and future updates can break things. Extremely fragile. +1 to @user4581301 's observation.

@Chuu It's broken.  Fix it, or it will continue to be broken.

This is what you get for trying to do binary serialization, it is just too fragile. Different compilers will generate different memory layouts, padding/alignment etc. Even compiler settings can do that. And that is even before you start communicating between 32/64 machines. Just take an available IPC mechanism like protobuf/grpc

@Chuu It is NEVER too late for refactoring specially not for fundamental design flaws. All you need to is to factor in all the hours you will lose because things keep breaking down

But now that you're here, I know of no such tool. The quickest thing I can come up with would be to use Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer. but note that even if the sizes are the same, the padding in the structures might not be, so the simple example linked is too trivial to be sufficient.

And hopefully the "architect" who pulled the steaming pile out of his rectal database learns something...

On the same platform, I expect the size of structs and offsets of struct members to be identical between gcc and clang.  (This expectation may not hold for very old versions of gcc and/or clang.)  On different platforms, I expect that the sizes/offsets will likely differ.  Is your IPC on the same platform?  Where "platform" also means that both apps are both 32-bit, or both 64-bit, but not a mix of those.  (Still, relying on this behavior is fragile, as others have already pointed out.)

@Eljay Same platform, built by the same build server.  I too was always under the assumption clang tried very hard to ensure gcc layout compatibility but given the current known facts it's the most likely culprit.

If you have a "large number of structs" being written to some shared memory buffer... you must have some way to tell which is which, e.g. [type tag][data] where you prefix the data with the type identifer, so why not change that to [type tag][data size][data] for the sake of debugging? Then you can validate the size when going to "deserialize" (memcpy into the destination type, e.g.).

I wouldn't try to ensure that struct members have the same size, offset within a struct, or (for that matter) the same representation of values (e.g. don't assume an int with value 47 is represented with the same set of bits on two platforms, even if they do have the same size).   Assume that ALL of those things can vary between implementation (since they can, particularly if you must support old and new compilers on different hosts).

As a very first step, add static_assert(sizeof(FooStruct)==16); to each struct.  Pick a size that works on your preferred platform.  Now you'll get some breaks when things go poorly, which is better than no breaks!
You'll have to write the sizes manually, hard code them in the file.
Then you'll get a size mismatch.  This will not catch offset mismatches on members, but those are (honestly) rarer, as usually an offset mismatch leads to a size difference (not always).
Once you have done this first step, start writing code to explicitly serialize wire types.  Have your wire protocol force going through such serialization, possibly through calling an ADL based function.
You can do the first step of this and implement bad binary serialization on existing types you are sending over the wire, and then incrementally make it not suck and be safer.
Other good early steps are checking for POD-ness (well, the sub-traits), and writing code that breaks classes down into members and serializes the members (there are some tricks you can do to partially automate this by hacking reflection into C++).
The point is you can make it better long before it is good, because good will take a bunch of work.

Pragmatic rather than perfect, but I've commented dozens of times that you're almost always being paid for "meets requirements", not "best".

@user4581301 Also, every step along the "better" path actually moves you towards "good" - identifying the list of structs that go over the wire is a great first step, and sizeof asserts will help do that, as an example.
